# How do I calculate the years from Jan 1st 1990 until today's date in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

How would I do this, without getting a negative value.?

Comment: What did you try, and why is it unsatisfactory for you?

Comment: I was given a code in class that I don't remember.

Comment: `select extract(year from current_date) - 1990 from dual`

Comment: So then, I should probably explain. Firstly - welcoem to Stack Overflow. Here generally we prefer you to try researching and then have a go at it yourself before you ask. So, in this case, you could google for "SQL dates years" and probably find some pretty good date functions to start out with. Then you'd think about the problem and what things you need to do, and have a go at applying those date functions. Maybe you wouldn't get the *right* answer, but you might get close.Then you'd come back here, and show us what you got... and we'd help you get the final bit.

Comment: This process helps you get better at coding too (rather than us just giving you the answer). :)

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be:

```
select months_between(sysdate, to_date('01-01-1990','dd-mm-yyyy'))/12 from dual;
```

you can use `round` function with desired precision to get a nicer number.

Comment: Please don't use NLS (language) dependent date literals - that introduces bad habits especially for someone learning Oracle.

Comment: `to_date('1-JAN-1990')`? Better use ANSI date literal if you don't like to mention the format model.

Answer (score 0):

[SYSDATE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions172.htm) gives you the current date.

Using **EXTRACT**:

```
SQL> SELECT extract(YEAR FROM sysdate) - 1990 years FROM dual;

     YEARS
----------
        25
```

Or,

Using **MONTHS_BETWEEN** and **FLOOR**:

```
SQL> SELECT floor(months_between(SYSDATE, to_date('01/01/1990','MM/DD/YYYY')) /12)
  2    AS "years"
  3  FROM dual;

     years
----------
        25
```